# Spring cannot resolve view within servlet

Tags: java, spring

I've added a new method/mapping to one of my servlets:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/prefs/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateUsersPrefs(@RequestBody Map<String, ArrayList> body, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

but when I send a request to this url I get a 500 Internal Server Error, with the following error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'user/prefs/order' in servlet with name 'appfinder'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I cannot for the life of me see why this is being reported.  Can anyone help with this?  I there is anymore information that I could provide, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of a void return, try a String return with the desired view name.  There are other options.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spring treats `@RequestMapping` methods with `void` return type [in the following manner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments):

> **`void`** - if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type `ServletResponse` / `HttpServletResponse` for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a `RequestToViewNameTranslator` (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature).

Therefore since there is no `HttpServletResponse` parameter to this method, Spring assumes that you would like the view name to be determined through a `RequestToViewNameTranslator`.

If you do not specify a particular `RequestToViewNameTranslator` to use in your context, then [the default implementation kicks in which will](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html):

> simply transforms the URI of the incoming request into a view name.

If you don't want the URI of the incoming request to be used as the view name, you have a few options:

1. Configure a custom `RequestToViewNameTranslator` with the behavior you would like
2. Add a `HttpServletResponse` parameter to this method if you would like to write to the response directly rather than View resolution take place.
3. Change the return type of this method to `String`, `View, or`ModelAndView` to be able to specify the view or view name within the method.

Comment: You have a small typo: "Therefore since there is no `HttpServletRequest`" should be "Therefore since there is no `HttpServlet*Response*`"

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and the reason was I was using tiles framework and did not mention the view name in tiles-def.xml. After configuring tiles-def.xml had the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.
I solved it by using the @ResponseBody annotation.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/prefs/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void updateUsersPrefs(@RequestBody Map<String, ArrayList> body, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
}
```